# What does colon (:) mean for getopts?

Tags: shell-script, posix, getopts

I am trying to parse options for my script with `getopts` and I decided that it would be best to read up on it in the POSIX standard, as it's usually extremely helpful. The [*DESCRIPTION* section](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/toc.htm) is fairly ambiguous in regard to the use of colon (:) in *optstring*, so I looked up how people use : with getopts on the internet and now I'm confused. What does colon do in commands like `getopts abc:d name` and how am I supposed to know just by reading the standard?

Comment: Look further down, in *Operands*: "If a character is followed by a <colon>, the option shall be expected to have an argument, which should be supplied as a separate argument."

Comment: which part of the description is ambiguous, exactly?

Answer (score 4):

A colon following an option letter indicates that the option takes an argument; this is described [in the “operands” section](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/getopts.html#tag_20_54_05):

> If a character is followed by a <colon>, the option shall be expected to have an argument, which should be supplied as a separate argument.

So `abc:d` means that the valid options are `-a`, `-b`, `-d` with no argument, and `-c` followed by an argument.

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I needed.

Comment: @NicolasDumitru Good! If this solves your issue, please consider [accepting the answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). Accepting an answer marks the issue as resolved.